# Find library returned null during migrating to tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I have written a code, which perfectly works on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5 with API 19). But when I try to upload the project onto the tablet with Android 4.2.2 it throws an error.

I use Eclipse. I cleaned all the projects. I have the same libraries in armeabi and armeabi-v7a.

Below is the log:

```
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PersonRecognizer.<init>(PersonRecognizer.java:42)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.PocketSphinxActivity$1.onManagerConnected(PocketSphinxActivity.java:249)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at org.opencv.android.AsyncServiceHelper$1.onServiceConnected(AsyncServiceHelper.java:318)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1106)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1123)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.<clinit>(opencv_contrib.java:104)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    ... 14 more
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_calib3d.<clinit>(opencv_calib3d.java:94)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    ... 18 more
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    ... 22 more
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    ... 26 more
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jniopencv_core from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo-1]: findLibrary returned null
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    ... 30 more
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_core from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo-1]: findLibrary returned null
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:481)
01-29 11:35:30.955: E/AndroidRuntime(16214):    ... 32 more
01-29 11:35:30.985: D/dalvikvm(16214): Rejecting registerization due to ushr-int/lit8 v4, v7, (#19)
01-29 11:35:30.995: D/dalvikvm(16214): Rejecting registerization due to ushr-int/lit8 v4, v7, (#19)
01-29 11:35:31.105: I/Process(16214): Sending signal. PID: 16214 SIG: 9
```

The part of the code is

```
PersonRecognizer(String path)
    {
      faceRecognizer =  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(2,8,8,8,200);
     // path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/facerecog/faces/";
     mPath=path;
     labelsFile= new labels(mPath);


    }
```

Comment: I guess you are using a native library code which is platform dependent and you have not generated the native lib for the SOC Arch  in which(tablet) your are uploading the code. it will be help full if you tell us the tablet make.

Comment: It's complaining about com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core. This one is a different package, not OpenCV's own android SDK. What do you need JavaCV for, when you already have OpenCV's android Java API working?

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m I didn't really get what you mean. Could you please, tell how can I generate lib for the tablet?

Comment: What model tablet are you using and what library you using in your project and if you have the source of the library project then better you take a look at https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html and a simple tutorial for NDK https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m I use Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 (GT-P5200) I installed the latest ndk 10 and I use OpenCV library 2.4.10. All worked perfectly for the Samsung Galaxy S5.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/Hy64nMqQnGw) may help. and you have to compile the library for yourself don't import the binaries directly.

**EDIT:**

From the comment i guess your are using samsung galaxy tab 10.1 which uses [Intel Atom](http://ark.intel.com/products/70098/Intel-Atom-Processor-Z2460-512K-Cache-up-to-1_60-GHz) which i again guess is a x86 architecture not [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A15) like the one used in your samsung Galaxy S5. so you have to compile the source for x86 or import the X86 (binaries)folder of your library to the libs folder of your project.

PS: Tutorial for compiling NDK from source for all platforms [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/using-the-android-x86-ndk-with-eclipse-and-porting-an-ndk-sample-app)

**EDIT:**
More info on your tablet [here](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Is-Intel-inside-the-Samsung-Galaxy-Tab-3-10.1_id43178)